# How to make this special binary-search algorithm more rusty?

Tags: algorithm, rust, binary-search

I am solving one binary search problem in [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/problems/search-in-rotated-sorted-array/).

I have accomplished such code:

```rust
struct Solution;
impl Solution {
    pub fn search(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> i32 {
        if nums.is_empty() {
            return -1;
        }
        if nums.len() == 1 {
            return if nums[0] == target { 0 } else { -1 };
        }
        let mut l = 0;
        let mut r = nums.len() - 1;

        while l <= r {
            let mid = (l + r) / 2 as usize;
            if nums[mid] == target {
                return mid as i32;
            }
            if nums[0] <= nums[mid] {
                if nums[0] <= target && target < nums[mid] {
                    r = mid - 1;
                } else {
                    l = mid + 1;
                }
            } else {
                if nums[mid] < target && target <= nums[n - 1] {
                    l = mid + 1;
                } else {
                    r = mid - 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

I have searched the standard library and found that it has an API: `binary_search_by`.  But since this is not a traditional binary search algorithm, I can't directly call the API.  I have also googled to try to find a more elegant Rust code but found nothing special.  Is there any idea to make this code rusty?

Comment: FYI: nowadays idiomatic Rust code is commonly called *rusty*.

Comment: This code does not compile (``error[E0412]: cannot find type `Solution` in this scope``, ``error[E0425]: cannot find value `n` in this scope``)

Comment: @trentcl This is caused by the leetcode site have an implicit `struct Solution;` definition, after adding this line the compile will pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, the interface provided by LeetCode is atrocious.  In order to make your code Rusty, I recommend writing your own interface first and then call it within the implementation of LeetCode's interface.  Here's why.

The full interface of the `search` function, imposed by LeetCode, is

```rust
impl Solution {
    pub fn search(nums: Vec<i32>, target: i32) -> i32 {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, *every single part* — no exaggeration here — of the interface can be improved.

- `struct Solution` is completely unnecessary in Rust.  It is much more idiomatic to define `search` as a free function or a trait method.
- The name `search` does not indicate the assumptions on `nums` clearly.  I prefer something along the lines of `rotated_binary_search`.
- Since the function only reads the contents of `nums`, there is no need to take ownership of the argument.  Moreover, the function can be made more generic by taking a slice instead of a `Vec` — see [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a `String` (`&String`), `Vec` (`&Vec`), or `Box` (`&Box`) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219).
- The `i32`s in the types of `nums` and `target` aren't unidiomatic per se, but since the same algorithm applies to any type with a total order, a generic type `T: Ord` is even better.
- The return type `i32` is problematic for two reasons:

  1. Rust uses `usize` for indexes, not `i32`, so returning `i32` introduces gratuitous type conversions.
  2. The absence of the target value is signaled by `-1`, which is error-prone, as the caller may easily forget to check the return value against `-1`.

  Instead, `Option<usize>` should be used so as to take advantage of the type system.

Here's the improved interface:

```rust
pub fn rotated_binary_search<T: Ord>(nums: &[T], target: &T) -> Option<usize> {
    // ...
}
```

---

The implementation is of much better quality than the interface.  The last line `return -1;` can be simplified to `-1` (without the semicolon), as the last expression in a function is implicitly the return value.  Then, we can adjust the `return`s to the new interface — `return Some(index)` and `return None` surely read better than `-1`, right? :)

Now, let's look at the implementation of [`binary_search`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search) (and [`binary_search_for`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.binary_search_by)) in the standard library for inspiration: ([ll. 2077–2176](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice/mod.rs.html#2077-2176), documentation and attributes omitted for brevity)

```rust
pub fn binary_search(&self, x: &T) -> Result<usize, usize>
where
    T: Ord,
{
    self.binary_search_by(|p| p.cmp(x))
}

pub fn binary_search_by<'a, F>(&'a self, mut f: F) -> Result<usize, usize>
where
    F: FnMut(&'a T) -> Ordering,
{
    let s = self;
    let mut size = s.len();
    if size == 0 {
        return Err(0);
    }
    let mut base = 0usize;
    while size > 1 {
        let half = size / 2;
        let mid = base + half;
        // SAFETY: the call is made safe by the following inconstants:
        // - `mid >= 0`: by definition
        // - `mid < size`: `mid = size / 2 + size / 4 + size / 8 ...`
        let cmp = f(unsafe { s.get_unchecked(mid) });
        base = if cmp == Greater { base } else { mid };
        size -= half;
    }
    // SAFETY: base is always in [0, size) because base <= mid.
    let cmp = f(unsafe { s.get_unchecked(base) });
    if cmp == Equal { Ok(base) } else { Err(base + (cmp == Less) as usize) }
}
```

The major difference is the use of a `(base, size)` pair instead of a `(low, high)` pair, which greatly simplifies the control flow.  You can also use `unsafe` to eliminate bound checks, but I wouldn't recommend that except when performance is absolutely critical.

Comment: All of the suggestions about the interface are great! For the implementation part, is there any rusty way to improve?

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin I added some thoughts about the implementation.  Please take a look :)